# Three foramen lying in one vertical plane

Tags: human-biology, anatomy, neuroanatomy, bone-biology, bio-mechanics

In the human skull we can see that 3 foramina named as supraorbital notch(foramen) , infraorbital foramen and mental foramen share a common vertical plane.

Is there any surgical significance of for such a geometry or its just a coincidence?[image]

Comment: Well, your cranial nerves all leave the brain just off center on both sides..

Comment: Many a times surgeons make use of geometries, so I ask the question. As far as I know all those foramen contain blood vessels too in addition to nerves.

Comment: Why pick only those three? Include *all* the foramen (like the foramens magnum and spinosum) and you'll see that they are oriented by function, not some forced geometric orientation.

Comment: I think you have taken it in a different way. My question does this geometry is made use by surgeons. It's made clear in the comment to theforestecologist.

Comment: @JM97 If that's what you mean, you should edit your question.

Comment: yes, edited. have a look at it.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "surgical significance"? They lie in roughly the same plane because humans have flat faces, and that fact might be useful. It's not clear what the question is.

Comment: I want to know whether this geometry is exploited during any surgical procedure or in craniometry.